# How to update a Firestore document after querying in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to update my document after I query the one I want to update. Here is the code I came up with:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("Social_Posts").where(data["postTitle"], isEqualTo: "postTitle").where(data["postContent"], isEqualTo: "postContent")
                  .snapshots()
                  .listen((event) {print("hh");});
```

Whenever I perform this query to find the correct document, I would like to update the document by adding a number to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to update the document from inside, The easier way to do that would definitely be to use the documentID and to increment the value Firestore has a special property, ***FieldValue.increment(1)***. Using this you can easily increment a field.

Lets say the field in the document you want to increment by 1, is "numberField".

**Updated code using async/await style:**

```
onTap: () async {

              setState(() {
                _title = data["postTitle"];
                _content= data["postContent"];
              });
            
              print(_title);
              print(_content);

              QuerySnaphot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("Social_Posts")
                  .where("postTitle" , isEqualTo: _title)
                  .where("postContent", isEqualTo: _content)
                  .getDocuments();

        if(snapshot.documents.isNotEmpty)
        {
            snapshot.documents.forEach((doc){
                doc.reference.updateData({"views" : FieldValue.increment(1),});
            });

        }
}
```

The numberField will be incremented without needing to make an extra call to know the present value.

EDIT : You were making a mistake in the **.where()** method

Comment: thank you for answering. I am getting the following error: Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Yes, one draw back of using this property is that, there has to exists a field named **"numberField"** of type integer to be incremented. You cannot use this while creating a document

Comment: Hi, I have added "numberfield" as a number to all my documents and i am still getting the same error: Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: According to my observations, "event.documents[0].documentID" is causing the error "Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

Comment: In that case make a small if check using this piece of code [ event.documents.isNotEmpty ]. This will return a bool value which is true if the documents are not empty. I have changed the above code. Have a look once

Comment: I don't see any changes to the code you have posted

Comment: I've added the if statement 1 min ago, do you still not see it?

Comment: Ok so i have added the code and I don't get any result, which confuses me because I have documents in the collection "Social_Posts". Perhaps my query is wrong.

Comment: Well you also have 2 additional "Where" queries attached right, so maybe no document is satisfying that condition. Were you receiving documents before changing the code?

Comment: I am outputting all of my documents in my UI, and when I print("document.length"), I get 15

Comment: How di i check if the string that is being checked is a valid field in the collection (a random document in the collection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217696/discussion-between-abdul-malik-and-aneesh-yalgi).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the document id you quired from inside the listen function in your case by using the `event.documents[0].documentID` assuming that your query returns one document only and then you can call the updateData method from Firestone package

Your code might looks like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("Social_Posts")
.where(data["postTitle"], isEqualTo: "postTitle")
    .where(data["postContent"], isEqualTo: "postContent")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((event) {

  Firestore.instance
      .collection("Social_Posts")
      .document(
      event.documents[0].documentID)
      .updateData(
      updateEvent) //Add here the new object you want to 
      .whenComplete(() {
    // You can add your desire action after the row is updated 
  }

 });
```

You can check package page for more information https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

And if you want to check a sample on how to perform CRUD functionalities you can check this repository: https://github.com/sayed3li97/flutter_firestore_crud

Comment: Thanks for replying. whenever I try to add "document.event.documents[0].documentID" to my code, it gives me an error saying "Undefined name 'document'."

Comment: @AneeshYalgi apologize for the mistake it is supposed to be event.documents[0].documentID